# How to replace component after click and pass data from the previous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Good evening! I think here won't help conditional render. I take id from that component, what i wanna replace. My idea is: list of components(tasks in todo-list) and each one have edit button. After click, i wanna catch id of this task and other data, pass them to another component and there already call UPDATE request after the users edits the information
At all, i need to realize this pseudocode:

```
<Icon bordered name='edit' link color='green' onClick={()=>(
     <TaskUpdate id={this.props.id} name={this.props.name} description={this.props.description}/>
)}/>
```

Comment: Do you mean work with state and props with conditional render like: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Yes, I do. Can I do it on this way?

Comment: You can design each item in list as standalone  component and use conditional render with state and props.

Comment: Sorry, can you show some code?Did not quite understand the point

Comment: Look at https://codepen.io/marekdano/pen/bVNYpq and TodoListItem

Comment: I looked, but still did not fully understand

Comment: Sorry, that what I can provide for you according to your question as I understood it.